Sketching the graph of the derivative of a piecewise function
When sketching the graph of the derivative of a piecewise function, can we directly check its differentiability without checking its continuity?
Some of the examples I have seen checked the continuity of the function first, the others went straight to checking its differentiability, so I'm really confused. I think we can skip the process of checking the continuity of the function, because if the function is discontinuous the function isn't differentiable, is it?
When testing for differentiability, one of the online videos suggested that when $x$ is approaching, for example, zero, we need to check only the limits of $f'(x)$ from the left and right, and don't need to separately evaluate $f'(0);$ why is that?

You need to check the continuity, or otherwise, there may exists function with the two-sided limit of derivatives equal but it is not even continuous. For example, consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x+1&\text{$x>1$}\\x&\text{$x\le1$}\end{cases}$$
Then $f'(x)\equiv1$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ and $f$ is clearly not differentiable on $x=1$ as the graph is broken.

To obtain $g'$ (or its graph) from a function $g,$ one doesn't need to directly test for continuity.  $\quad$ Regarding your example function $f:$ $\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac {f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$ doesn't exist, so $f$ has no right derivative at $1,$ so $f'(1)$ doesn't exist; none of this involves testing for continuity, only differentiation (from first principles).

Yah the easiest reason for the limit of derivative quotient does not exist is because $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1^+}[f(x)-f(1)]\ne0$, which implies the discontinuity of $f$ at $x=1$, but you are absolutely right.

"Differentiable" implies "continuous" so you don't need to check continuity first to examine the derivative.
"Not continuous" implies "not differentiable" so classifying discontinuities could still give useful info about the shape of the derivative graph since you can use them to identify some non-differentiable points without taking a derivative. For example it may be useful to know if the original graph has as a removable or irremovable discontinuity. But "continuous" does not imply "differentiable" so you would still need to check differentiability explicitly.
For your last question:
"When testing the differentiability, one of the online videos suggested that we only need to test the limit of $f'(x)$ from the left and right, when $x$ is approaching, for example, zero. We don't need to test $f(0)$, why is that?
Assuming you mean check $f(0)$ for the continuity of $f(x)$ at $x = 0$ -- since differentiability implies continuity if you show that $f'(0)$ exists then you will know $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$.
edit: if you check differentiability and $f$ has non-differentiable points you won't know which of those points are also discontinuous. checking continuity first, or really checking both, gives a more complete picture of $f$.


When sketching the graph of the derivative of a piecewise function, can we directly check its differentiability without checking its continuity?  I think we can skip the process of checking the continuity of the function, because if the function is discontinuous the function isn't differentiable, is it?


Yes—for the reason that you point out—differentiating a function does not require checking its continuity, even at a piecewise function's pieces' endpoints.

In particular, consider this example from one of the posted answers:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{$x\le1$}\\x+1&\text{$x>1$}\end{cases}.$$ Now, $f'(1),$ if it exists, equals $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}\frac {f(x)-f(1)}{x-1},$ by definition.
But $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac {f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$ doesn't exist.
Hence, $f'(1)$ is undefined. (We've determined this without checking for continuity.)
Therefore, the graph of $f'$ is the horizontal line $f'(x)=1$ but with a hole at $x=1.$

Furthermore, continuity doesn't guarantee differentiability: the function $$h(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{$x<0$}\\x&\text{$x\ge0$}\end{cases}$$ is continuous but not differentiable at $0.$ This non-differentiability is again determinable from the definition of derivative.

I guess a more practical answer to your question is that at a piecewise function's pieces' endpoints, differentiation must be peformed from first principles, and that in the implication $$f(x)=x\textbf{ on a neighbourhood of }\boldsymbol c\implies f'(c)=1,$$ the boldfaced condition shouldn't be neglected.


